# Can't open heroku application connecting to firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, heroku, webpack, firebase-authentication

After Connecting to Firebase and add the following domain :
[Heroku Domain](https://github.com/MohammedNagar/react-todo) to the authorized domains, I get the following error when i try to [`Heroku open`]:

> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be
>   served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

---

The logs are so confusing :

> 2017-10-15T19:43:14.249135+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
>   desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
>   host=aqueous-lake-87719.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=c837ed1c-0d44-497b-88d6-0cc72e062771 fwd="197.37.44.69"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http

---

**My Package.json :**

```
"name": "boilerplate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Simple react application",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test karma start",
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "npm run build && node server.js"
  },
```

---

**My server.js :**

```
var express = require('express');

// Create our app
var app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(function (req, res, next){
  if (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] === 'https') {
    res.redirect('http://' + req.hostname + req.url);
  } else {
    next();
  }
});

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.listen(PORT, function () {
  console.log('Express server is up on port ' + PORT);
});
```

---

**The Application on Github:**
[React-Todo](https://github.com/MohammedNagar/react-todo)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I deployed your app on heroku and found the same `503` error. Then i ran `npm run build` locally and realized it doesn't work. Because `redux` is missing. It may have worked for you as you may `redux` installed globally.

After adding

```
"redux": "^3.7.2",
```

To the `package.json` and pushing the app again, it works fine and I am able to access the app, though it has a JS error in initializing the Firebase connection, which you can fix easily

[image: Firebase error]